# Adding Fling Gesture to an image view - Android

Tags: android, imageview, gestures, onfling

Okay I have been referencing the code here: [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

but just can not get it to work. In my main activity I have a simple image defined. I want to detect a fling on the image. Here is my code below. The onclick method at the bottom is empty. Is it because of this? I left it blank because in the other code sample its not what I want. I just want a simple toast to pop up saying fling right or fling left.

```
public class GestureRightLeft extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    ImageView peek;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        peek =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.peek);
        peek.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluestrip);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(GestureRightLeft.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(GestureRightLeft.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

Comment: See also [How to add a gesture detector to a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054908/how-to-add-a-gesture-detector-to-a-view-in-android)

Answer (score 91):

Here's the simpliest working version of flinger I can think of.
You can actually tie it to any component, not only ImageView.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private void onCreate() {
        final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
        final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }               

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Right to left
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Left to right
            }

            if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Bottom to top
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // Top to bottom
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

No activity onClickListener though (if you don't need to catch any onclick actions)
It captures not only horizontal, but vertical also (just delete vertical part if you don't need it), and horizontal swipes have priority as you can see.
In places where method returns (nad where my comments are) just call your method or whatever :)

Comment: Use `final GestureDetector gdt = GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());` instead, per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector(android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener)

Comment: This is more like paging. A good flinging example can be found here : http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html

Comment: @Radu, read the link @Snicolas provided. You have to override `onDown` and return true.

Comment: I don't fully understand the code, but IMO this can't be correct, because `onFling` is returning `false` in all paths of execution.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
  });
```

Comment: **+1** thanks dude it worked for me.. i return true instead of false . now my problem solved

Comment: @contactmeandroid inside if condition also i return true; it worked for me.

Comment: @Ganapathy It worked but  on swipe I wanted to drag the image and I was not able to do it

Comment: drag and drop framework in android may help you.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Simplified return !mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

Answer (score 10):

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return !gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

some of the precondition

1) setonClick method

```
image.setOnClickListener(this);
```

2) set your gesture detection in onTouch()

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwingGestureDetection((mContext),image,a));
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

3) create SwingGestureDetection class and implement all method

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float arg2,float arg3) {
    if (start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX()) {
        System.out.println("next...swing");
    } else {
        System.out.println("previois...swing");
    }
}
```

4) pass your imageview in constructor

```
public SwingGestureDetection(Context con,ImageView image,int pos) {
    mContext = con;
    this.image = image;
    this.position = pos;
}
```

This is perfect work for me.if any query then put comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try to read:
http://illusionsandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/adding-fling-gesture-listener-to-view.html

It allow you to separate your activity implementation from your custom listener. It is simply a refactoring of the solution reported by Alex Orlov

Answer (score 2):

If you dont like to create a separate class or make code complex,
You can just create a GestureDetector variable inside OnTouchListener and make your code more easier

namVyuVar can be any name of the View on which you need to set the listner

```
namVyuVar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent MsnEvtPsgVal)
    {
        flingActionVar.onTouchEvent(MsnEvtPsgVal);
        return true;
    }

    GestureDetector flingActionVar = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
    {
        private static final int flingActionMinDstVac = 120;
        private static final int flingActionMinSpdVac = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent fstMsnEvtPsgVal, MotionEvent lstMsnEvtPsgVal, float flingActionXcoSpdPsgVal, float flingActionYcoSpdPsgVal)
        {
            if(fstMsnEvtPsgVal.getX() - lstMsnEvtPsgVal.getX() > flingActionMinDstVac && Math.abs(flingActionXcoSpdPsgVal) > flingActionMinSpdVac)
            {
                // TskTdo :=> On Right to Left fling

                return false;
            }
            else if (lstMsnEvtPsgVal.getX() - fstMsnEvtPsgVal.getX() > flingActionMinDstVac && Math.abs(flingActionXcoSpdPsgVal) > flingActionMinSpdVac)
            {
                // TskTdo :=> On Left to Right fling

                return false;
            }

            if(fstMsnEvtPsgVal.getY() - lstMsnEvtPsgVal.getY() > flingActionMinDstVac && Math.abs(flingActionYcoSpdPsgVal) > flingActionMinSpdVac)
            {
                // TskTdo :=> On Bottom to Top fling

                return false;
            }
            else if (lstMsnEvtPsgVal.getY() - fstMsnEvtPsgVal.getY() > flingActionMinDstVac && Math.abs(flingActionYcoSpdPsgVal) > flingActionMinSpdVac)
            {
                // TskTdo :=> On Top to Bottom fling

                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a method like ImageView.setOnGestureListener, there is none. You can go look at the Android source code. Your best option is to handle it in onTouch() of the View object.

This is the simplest GestureDetector I can make.

I have a class called GenesMotionDetector.java. Here's the code for it:

```
package gene.com.motioneventssample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GenesMotionDetector extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nothing);
        gestureScanner= new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(),this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        System.out.println("Inside onTouchEvent() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onDown() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onFling() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onLongPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onScroll() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onShowPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onSingleTapUp() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The corresponding XML layout file for that class is nothing.xml. Here's the code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:background="#17528c"
        android:text="testing"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="#f8af20"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, taking the simplest GestureDetector I can make (from above) and modifying it for what you want, I get this:

```
package gene.com.motioneventssample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GenesMotionDetector3 extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
    ImageView mView3;

    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    MotionEvent initialME, finalME;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nothing);


        mView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Gesture detection
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(), this);

        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialME= event;

                        if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                            // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the velocity of a motion.
                            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        }
                        else {
                            // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
                            mVelocityTracker.clear();
                        }
                        // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                        // When you want to determine the velocity, call
                        // computeCurrentVelocity(). Then call getXVelocity()
                        // and getYVelocity() to retrieve the velocity for each pointer ID.
                        mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        finalME=event;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        // Return a VelocityTracker object back to be re-used by others.
                        mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                        break;
                }
                return onFling(initialME, finalME, mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity(), mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                //return false;
            }
        };

        mView3.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        System.out.println("Inside onTouchEvent() of GenesMotionDetector.java");

        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onDown() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onFling() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        System.out.println("e1= "+ e1);
        System.out.println("e2= "+ e2);
        System.out.println("velocityX= "+ velocityX);
        System.out.println("velocityY= "+ velocityY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onLongPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onScroll() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onShowPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onSingleTapUp() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }
}
```

You might as well just handle everything in onTouch(). I'm basically getting the gestures in onTouch and passing it to onFling().

Answer (score 0):

Design your layout with ImageView.
Add `setOnTouchListener`to imageView.`imageview.setOnTouchListener(this)`.add unimplemented method `View.OnTouchListener`.Then `onTouch` method you can implemtn your guesture logic.This sample tells you left to right and right to left guesture,

```
float x1,x2;
float y1, y2;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch ( event.getAction() ){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            x1 = event.getX();
            y1 = event.getY();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
            x2 = event.getX();
            y2 = event.getY();

            if ( x1<x2 ) {
                //implement what you need to do here
            }
            if ( x1>x2 ) {
                //implement what you need to do here
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The answer does not provide the fling logic, OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example for kotlin:

```
val flingGesture = GestureDetector(requireContext(), object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        // your action here
        return true
    }
})
```

Set to any view:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener{ _, motionEvent ->
    flingGesture.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    return@setOnTouchListener true
}
```