# Android Gestures over an image

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm continuing my learning with android and have now reached the point where I'm plating with gestures.

What I have so far is a activity screen and I can pop a Toast up when the gesture pattern is recognised.

What I'd like to do is display an image centre screen, which in this case will be a image of the gesture for the user to copy. I'd also like the image to be the only area for the gesture detection. This would me the user loosely traces the gesture, although following the guide exactly is **not** what I'm trying to achieve.

I think I need to extend ImageView with a GestureListener, but I'm a little unclear on how to do that. Could anyone supply and example or point me to a good tutorial please?

Thanks in advance,

Ric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android) to get sample codes on guesture listeners with image view.

Also you [click here](http://illusionsandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/adding-fling-gesture-listener-to-view.html)  to get tutorial on guesture listener

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/multitouch-and-gesture-detection-part-1) tutorial.

I hope that help you.

Answer (score -1):

[This tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content) will teach you the basics about what you want to do.