# Android Gesture detection over an Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, gesture-recognition

I am creating an android application to detect the gestures. For this I have referred [the following link](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Gestures-in-Android).

In the main.xml, they are using `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView` to find the gesture. 
But I want to use `Imageview` instead of `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView`.

Note: I have searched in the internet. I got the following ref. But this is not helped me.

[Android Gestures over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6137069/1584121)

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **read** the documentation of [`GestureOverlayView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html):

> A transparent overlay for gesture input that can be placed on top of other widgets or contain other widgets

Note the two words *transparent* and *overlay*.  You can use it on top of any view - just use an appropriate Layout (Hint: try `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) or add views to it (as it is a sub-class of `FrameLayout`).

There are tutorials out there like this: [Android Gestures - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html).