# Android scroll images by page - which control?

Tags: android

Im fairly new to andorid and getting to grips with the UI elements.

I have a collection of full size images which i wish to be able to page through, horizontally, by scrolling left or right.

I do not want a scroll effect where you could see half of one image and half of the next, i want to page so only one full image is visible at any one time.

My question is, which control is best to achieve this?

Im currently thinking just an ImageView and handle a gesture to load in the next image. I have looked at the gallery but this seems to not suit what im trying to do. The lists will give a scroll, not a paged effect which i dont want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageView` with the gesture is probably the easiest way of doing this. See [Adding Fling Gesture to an image view - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android) for a reasonable example.

Answer (score 2):

I think your are on the right track, but might want to put your ImageView into a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).  This will allow you to have a nice animated transition when you switch images.

You should also take a look at the [PagedView](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GreenDroid/src/greendroid/widget/PagedView.java) widget from the [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library.