# Slide Unlocker ImageView ViewFlipper

Tags: android, view, imageview, unlock

I want to develop an unlocker. You can unlock by sliding to the right (just like on the iPhone).

Wich is the best method to implement this? Should I use a ViewFlipper and a GestureDetector?
I have already tried this, but I could slide anywhere on the screen to unlock.
The ImageView of the ViewFlipper should slide with my finger and only if my finger is directly on the imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android) for gestures on images, or any view for that matter.