# Slide Unlocker ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, slide, unlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slide Unlocker ImageView ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182515/slide-unlocker-imageview-viewflipper)

I want to create a Slide Unlocker (just like on the iPhone)

I can´t use gestures for that, right? Because I should can change the position of the ImageView of the Unlocker permanently. The ImageView should "follow" my finger.

Do I have to use a simple onTouchListener on the ImageView?

Comment: You posted the same question 40 minutes before this one.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182515/slide-unlocker-imageview-viewflipper

Comment: were u able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on your accept rate, you're more likely to get better help if you don't have 0%.

You could likely repurpose a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) to do what you want.

The other option is to pull out the [SlidingTab](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java) java file from the Android source code and include it in your own project, and make use of it how you like. Since this Object was not included in the public APIs you must provide your own copy of it if you wish to use it in your application.

Comment: How to use the sliding tab ?