# ViewPager won't swipe to left when swiping over an EditText

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` containing `EditText` fields (1 per page).
When I scroll to the left, the swipe gesture in consumed by the `EditText` and the page won't change. However when I swipe to the right the swipe gesture is intercepted by the `ViewPager` as I expect.

How can I force the `ViewPager` to intercept any horizontal swipe gesture?

Answer (score 0):

First: that's very odd as I'd expect the `ViewPager` to consume all horizontal swipes automatically unless you are overriding some gesture related method. For example, I've used a `MapFragment` within a `ViewPager` before and unless I scrolled up on the map first, the horizontal swipes would always trigger the view pager.

Second, I don't think you can make your `ViewPager` more inclusive than it already is in picking up x-direction swipes. What I would do instead is simply [add a gesture listener to your edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android). If you do this, you could use an `Inteface` to the `ViewPager` activity to trigger the page to change on swipe.

Btw this should also still allow clicks on the `EditText` itself so you could still use it as intended.