# Android tile movement

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, tile, motion

I'm looking to implement movement from character to character on a tiled board. I have a 7x7 board set up with each tile representing a character. The player is able to move in up to the 8 directions around the tile (providing proper game logic). I am able to accurately get the character at a given tile based on a `onTouch() Action_Down`.

For a more elegant solution though I am looking to press and drag to move between tiles/create words. I'm not exactly sure where I should start with this.

I can figure out all the logic for appropriate moves etc. But my question is how to recognize a left movement from 1 position to another as selecting tiles?

My current idea is to have hard boarders but that will not work for diagonal. Then my next idea is to have diagonal boarders instead so like:

[image: this]

This solution seems a little complex though. Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Are you trying to differentiate a lateral or vertical movement from a diagonal movement programmatically? Or is this a question about what your UI should look like?

Comment: My question is: What is the proper implementation to differentiate lateral/vertical movement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android does this help?