# Fling view animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I have spend two days browsing the web for how to animate a view once a fling gesture has been detected on a view. I have read SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android). I can animate the view with a fragment transaction or by animating it to where the user has dragged the view to in the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, and when ACTION_UP then use scrollTo() method to scroll the view off the screen. But none of these solutions makes a smooth "fling" or "slide". How can I do this? I have tried using Scroller and OverScroller without any luck.

Comment: use [FlingAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/animation/FlingAnimation.html)

Comment: Cannot get it to resolve symbol. I have added the dependency for it.

Comment: what dependency?

Comment: You need to add this dependency 
compile "com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:26.0.0-beta2" according to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/physics-based-animation.html

Comment: yes, but 25.4 is enough

Comment: Still after adding it, it cannot resolve FlingAnimation, but DynamicAnimation it can.

Comment: just used 26.0.0-beta1 with no problems

Comment: Like this? FlingAnimation fling = new FlingAnimation(view, DynamicAnimation.SCROLL_X);

Comment: yes, just like this

Comment: Okay it can resolve SpringAnimation. This is just epic troll....

Comment: [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/fling-animation.html) you have `FlingAnimation` related samples, just follow them

Comment: That is the code I'm trying to implement. Do you need anything else than this dependency? Can I only create the FlingAnimation inside an onFling method or something crazy?

Comment: Don't know what to do then. Impossible to solve it..

Comment: It is actually not. Any idea why it isn't?